Python Sounddevice / sound is played way to fast over the speaker
i'm trying to stream or play data with python with the module sounddevice.
However when it is streaming or playing over my speakers it is way to fast to understand anything.
when i'm playing the wav file normally via for example VLC everything is ok.
i can't figure out what the problem is
2 bits of codes i tried: one with sd.play other with streaming option:
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import wave
from piper.voice import PiperVoice

sd.default.device = 1
filename = 'temp.wav'

voicedir = "./piper/" #Where onnx model files are stored on my machine
model = voicedir+"en_GB-alan-low.onnx"
voice = PiperVoice.load(model)
wav_file = wave.open(filename, 'w')
text = "This is an example of text-to-speech using Piper TTS."
audio = voice.synthesize(text,wav_file)`

# Extract data and sampling rate from file
data, fs = sf.read(filename)
sd.play(data, fs)
status = sd.wait()  # Wait until file is done playing

and second code:
import sounddevice as sd
from piper.voice import PiperVoice
import numpy as np

voicedir = "./piper/" #Where onnx model files are stored on my machine
model = voicedir+"en_GB-alan-low.onnx"
voice = PiperVoice.load(model)
text = "This is an example of text-to-speech using Piper TTS."


# Setup a sounddevice OutputStream with appropriate parameters
# The sample rate and channels should match the properties of the PCM data
sd.default.device = 1
sd.default.samplerate = 16000
samplerate = sd.query_devices(device=1)
stream = sd.RawOutputStream(channels=1, dtype='int16')
print(voice.config.sample_rate)

stream.start()
for audio_bytes in voice.synthesize_stream_raw(text):
    int_data = np.frombuffer(audio_bytes, dtype=np.int16)
    stream.write(int_data)
stream.stop()
stream. Close()type here

i tried different settings, i want to stream the data to my speaker in the same speed as for example vlc is using

wild guess;  Sample rate of your output stream differs from sample rate of the piper - even the readme mentions that these should match. Check your settings

hi rasjani, i used a different model to match my sample rate from my speaker, i can only select sample rate 16000 for my speaker what is matching the sample rate of the low models of piper. at my first test i used medium model which is using sample rate 22050 what i could not select for my speaker that is the reason i switched to another piper model
